# How why is `Constraint.Skip` not recognized in Pyomo?

Tags: python, pyomo

I know how to create expressions using rules in Pyomo.  However, when I try to use Constraint.Skip it doesn’t seem to be recognized as an attribute.  Here’s my minimal example:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe 

m = pe.ConcreteModel() 
m.x = pe.Var() 
from constraint import * 

def expression_rule(m, i): 
    if i: 
        # generate the constraint 
        expr = 0 <= m.x   
    else: 
        # skip this index 
        expr = Constraint.Skip 
    return expr 

n=2 
m.constraints_skip_rule = pe.Constraint(range(n), rule = expression_rule)
```

When I dig into the source code, I see clearly that `Constraint.Skip` is used many places, and the `__all__` at the top of the `constraint.py` file includes  `Constraint`.  Why is it not recognized in the code above?  Perhaps I'm missing some basic knowledge about how libraries work.

Comment: you imported with a rename to `pe`.  Try:  `pe.Constraint.Skip`

Comment: and ditch the `from constraint import *`

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that one overrides the other.  I would have thought that the latest import takes precedence rather than the first one - no?    
Anyway, thanks.  Make it an answer and I'll gladly accept.

Comment: I don't think the `constraint` you imported is associated.  Not sure what that is.  The one you want is:  `from pyomo.environ import Constraint`.

Comment: There's a file called `constraint.py` in the `pyomo` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways. In both cases, I would remove `from constraint import *`.

First way:
change your skip statement to `expr = pe.Constraint.Skip` . The point being that you have imported the pyomo environment as `pe`.

Second way:
Only import the classes from pyomo that you need/plan to use. Avoid importing * to make it less ambiguous what calls you are making.

```
from pyomo.environ import (ConcreteModel, Var, Constraint)  

m = ConcreteModel() 
m.x = Var() 

def expression_rule(m, i): 
    if i: 
        # generate the constraint 
        expr = 0 <= m.x   
    else: 
        # skip this index 
        expr = Constraint.Skip 
    return expr 

n=2 
m.constraints_skip_rule = Constraint(range(n), rule = expression_rule) `
```